# Laptop mousepad too fast

Tags: laptop, mouse

Sometimes, after the laptop wakes up by opening the lid, the mousepad is too fast and also detecting movement when touching the switches. Also scrolling (two fingers on the pad) is not working.

Most of the time, the mousepad is working correctly.
After a reboot, the mousepad is always working correctly.

Laptop info (first part of lshw):

```
    description: Notebook
    product: X541UAK
    vendor: ASUSTeK COMPUTER INC.
    version: 1.0
    serial: H7N0CX07X701289
    width: 64 bits
    capabilities: smbios-3.0.0 dmi-3.0.0 smp vsyscall32
    configuration: boot=normal chassis=notebook family=X uuid=48374E30-4358-3037-5837-303132383941
  *-core
       description: Motherboard
       product: X541UAK
       vendor: ASUSTeK COMPUTER INC.
       physical id: 0
       version: 1.0
       serial: QCCXKF2FB72601879
       slot: MIDDLE
     *-firmware
          description: BIOS
          vendor: American Megatrends Inc.
          physical id: 0
          version: X541UAK.305
          date: 05/23/2017
          size: 64KiB
          capacity: 8MiB
          capabilities: pci upgrade shadowing cdboot bootselect socketedrom edd int13floppy1200 int13floppy720 int13floppy2880 int5printscreen int9keyboard int14serial int17printer acpi usb smartbattery biosbootspecification uefi
```

There is no "mouse" related stuff in lshw.
The laptop is running Fedora 34, but also older versions had the same problem. Other laptops (also with Fedora do not have this issue)

dmesg after opening the lid:

```
[Mon Aug 29 17:00:02 2022] cni-podman1: port 3(veth36992a86) entered disabled state
[Mon Aug 29 17:00:02 2022] device veth36992a86 left promiscuous mode
[Mon Aug 29 17:00:02 2022] cni-podman1: port 3(veth36992a86) entered disabled state
[Mon Aug 29 17:00:03 2022] cni-podman1: port 2(veth2dc87913) entered disabled state
[Mon Aug 29 17:00:03 2022] device veth2dc87913 left promiscuous mode
[Mon Aug 29 17:00:03 2022] cni-podman1: port 2(veth2dc87913) entered disabled state
[Mon Aug 29 17:00:04 2022] cni-podman1: port 1(vetha294b27e) entered disabled state
[Mon Aug 29 17:00:04 2022] device vetha294b27e left promiscuous mode
[Mon Aug 29 17:00:04 2022] cni-podman1: port 1(vetha294b27e) entered disabled state
[Mon Aug 29 17:00:06 2022] IPv6: ADDRCONF(NETDEV_CHANGE): veth005c1790: link becomes ready
[Mon Aug 29 17:00:06 2022] IPv6: ADDRCONF(NETDEV_CHANGE): eth0: link becomes ready
[Mon Aug 29 17:00:06 2022] cni-podman1: port 1(veth005c1790) entered blocking state
[Mon Aug 29 17:00:06 2022] cni-podman1: port 1(veth005c1790) entered disabled state
[Mon Aug 29 17:00:06 2022] device veth005c1790 entered promiscuous mode
[Mon Aug 29 17:00:06 2022] cni-podman1: port 1(veth005c1790) entered blocking state
[Mon Aug 29 17:00:06 2022] cni-podman1: port 1(veth005c1790) entered forwarding state
[Mon Aug 29 17:00:07 2022] IPv6: ADDRCONF(NETDEV_CHANGE): veth70a9cf01: link becomes ready
[Mon Aug 29 17:00:07 2022] IPv6: ADDRCONF(NETDEV_CHANGE): eth0: link becomes ready
[Mon Aug 29 17:00:07 2022] cni-podman1: port 2(veth70a9cf01) entered blocking state
[Mon Aug 29 17:00:07 2022] cni-podman1: port 2(veth70a9cf01) entered disabled state
[Mon Aug 29 17:00:07 2022] device veth70a9cf01 entered promiscuous mode
[Mon Aug 29 17:00:07 2022] cni-podman1: port 2(veth70a9cf01) entered blocking state
[Mon Aug 29 17:00:07 2022] cni-podman1: port 2(veth70a9cf01) entered forwarding state
[Mon Aug 29 17:00:09 2022] IPv6: ADDRCONF(NETDEV_CHANGE): veth20f6a596: link becomes ready
[Mon Aug 29 17:00:09 2022] IPv6: ADDRCONF(NETDEV_CHANGE): eth0: link becomes ready
[Mon Aug 29 17:00:09 2022] cni-podman1: port 3(veth20f6a596) entered blocking state
[Mon Aug 29 17:00:09 2022] cni-podman1: port 3(veth20f6a596) entered disabled state
[Mon Aug 29 17:00:09 2022] device veth20f6a596 entered promiscuous mode
[Mon Aug 29 17:00:09 2022] cni-podman1: port 3(veth20f6a596) entered blocking state
[Mon Aug 29 17:00:09 2022] cni-podman1: port 3(veth20f6a596) entered forwarding state
[Mon Aug 29 17:04:30 2022] PM: suspend entry (deep)
[Mon Aug 29 17:04:30 2022] Filesystems sync: 0.129 seconds
[Mon Aug 29 17:04:30 2022] Freezing user space processes ... (elapsed 0.003 seconds) done.
[Mon Aug 29 17:04:30 2022] OOM killer disabled.
[Mon Aug 29 17:04:30 2022] Freezing remaining freezable tasks ... (elapsed 0.001 seconds) done.
[Mon Aug 29 17:04:30 2022] printk: Suspending console(s) (use no_console_suspend to debug)
[Mon Aug 29 17:04:30 2022] sd 0:0:0:0: [sda] Synchronizing SCSI cache
[Mon Aug 29 17:04:30 2022] sd 0:0:0:0: [sda] Stopping disk
[Mon Aug 29 17:04:30 2022] PM: suspend devices took 0.297 seconds
[Mon Aug 29 17:04:30 2022] ACPI: EC: interrupt blocked
[Mon Aug 29 17:04:30 2022] ACPI: PM: Preparing to enter system sleep state S3
[Mon Aug 29 17:04:30 2022] ACPI: EC: event blocked
[Mon Aug 29 17:04:30 2022] ACPI: EC: EC stopped
[Mon Aug 29 17:04:30 2022] ACPI: PM: Saving platform NVS memory
[Mon Aug 29 17:04:30 2022] Disabling non-boot CPUs ...
[Mon Aug 29 17:04:30 2022] smpboot: CPU 1 is now offline
[Mon Aug 29 17:04:30 2022] smpboot: CPU 2 is now offline
[Mon Aug 29 17:04:30 2022] smpboot: CPU 3 is now offline
[Mon Aug 29 17:04:30 2022] ACPI: PM: Low-level resume complete
[Mon Aug 29 17:04:30 2022] ACPI: EC: EC started
[Mon Aug 29 17:04:30 2022] ACPI: PM: Restoring platform NVS memory
[Mon Aug 29 17:04:30 2022] Enabling non-boot CPUs ...
[Mon Aug 29 17:04:30 2022] x86: Booting SMP configuration:
[Mon Aug 29 17:04:30 2022] smpboot: Booting Node 0 Processor 1 APIC 0x2
[Mon Aug 29 17:04:30 2022] CPU1 is up
[Mon Aug 29 17:04:30 2022] smpboot: Booting Node 0 Processor 2 APIC 0x1
[Mon Aug 29 17:04:30 2022] CPU2 is up
[Mon Aug 29 17:04:30 2022] smpboot: Booting Node 0 Processor 3 APIC 0x3
[Mon Aug 29 17:04:30 2022] CPU3 is up
[Mon Aug 29 17:04:30 2022] ACPI: PM: Waking up from system sleep state S3
[Mon Aug 29 17:04:30 2022] ACPI: EC: interrupt unblocked
[Mon Aug 29 17:04:30 2022] ACPI: EC: event unblocked
[Mon Aug 29 17:04:30 2022] ath: phy0: ASPM enabled: 0x43
[Mon Aug 29 17:04:30 2022] sd 0:0:0:0: [sda] Starting disk
[Mon Aug 29 17:04:30 2022] xhci_hcd 0000:00:14.0: xHC error in resume, USBSTS 0x411, Reinit
[Mon Aug 29 17:04:30 2022] usb usb1: root hub lost power or was reset
[Mon Aug 29 17:04:30 2022] usb usb2: root hub lost power or was reset
[Mon Aug 29 17:04:30 2022] i915 0000:00:02.0: [drm] [ENCODER:94:DDI A/PHY A] is disabled/in DSI mode with an ungated DDI clock, gate it
[Mon Aug 29 17:04:30 2022] i915 0000:00:02.0: [drm] [ENCODER:102:DDI B/PHY B] is disabled/in DSI mode with an ungated DDI clock, gate it
[Mon Aug 29 17:04:30 2022] i915 0000:00:02.0: [drm] [ENCODER:117:DDI C/PHY C] is disabled/in DSI mode with an ungated DDI clock, gate it
[Mon Aug 29 17:04:30 2022] i2c_hid_acpi i2c-ELAN1200:00: failed to change power setting.
[Mon Aug 29 17:04:30 2022] PM: dpm_run_callback(): acpi_subsys_resume+0x0/0x70 returns -121
[Mon Aug 29 17:04:30 2022] i2c_hid_acpi i2c-ELAN1200:00: PM: failed to resume async: error -121
[Mon Aug 29 17:04:31 2022] ata1: SATA link up 6.0 Gbps (SStatus 133 SControl 300)
[Mon Aug 29 17:04:31 2022] ata3: SATA link down (SStatus 4 SControl 300)
[Mon Aug 29 17:04:31 2022] ata2: SATA link down (SStatus 4 SControl 300)
[Mon Aug 29 17:04:31 2022] ata1.00: configured for UDMA/133
[Mon Aug 29 17:04:31 2022] ahci 0000:00:17.0: port does not support device sleep
[Mon Aug 29 17:04:31 2022] usb 1-6: reset high-speed USB device number 2 using xhci_hcd
[Mon Aug 29 17:04:31 2022] usb 1-8: reset full-speed USB device number 4 using xhci_hcd
[Mon Aug 29 17:04:31 2022] usb 1-8: device firmware changed
[Mon Aug 29 17:04:31 2022] PM: resume devices took 0.762 seconds
[Mon Aug 29 17:04:31 2022] OOM killer enabled.
[Mon Aug 29 17:04:31 2022] Restarting tasks ... 
[Mon Aug 29 17:04:31 2022] usb 1-8: USB disconnect, device number 4
[Mon Aug 29 17:04:31 2022] done.
[Mon Aug 29 17:04:31 2022] PM: suspend exit
[Mon Aug 29 17:04:31 2022] RTL8208 Fast Ethernet r8169-0-202:00: attached PHY driver (mii_bus:phy_addr=r8169-0-202:00, irq=MAC)
[Mon Aug 29 17:04:31 2022] usb 1-8: new full-speed USB device number 5 using xhci_hcd
[Mon Aug 29 17:04:31 2022] usb 1-8: New USB device found, idVendor=04ca, idProduct=3010, bcdDevice= 0.01
[Mon Aug 29 17:04:31 2022] usb 1-8: New USB device strings: Mfr=0, Product=0, SerialNumber=0
[Mon Aug 29 17:04:31 2022] r8169 0000:02:00.2 enp2s0f2: Link is Down
[Mon Aug 29 17:04:31 2022] usb 1-8: USB disconnect, device number 5
[Mon Aug 29 17:04:32 2022] usb 1-8: new full-speed USB device number 6 using xhci_hcd
[Mon Aug 29 17:04:33 2022] IPv6: ADDRCONF(NETDEV_CHANGE): wlp3s0: link becomes ready
[Mon Aug 29 17:04:37 2022] usb 1-8: New USB device found, idVendor=04ca, idProduct=3010, bcdDevice= 0.02
[Mon Aug 29 17:04:37 2022] usb 1-8: New USB device strings: Mfr=0, Product=0, SerialNumber=0
```

I removed some wlp3s0 lines, related to the wifi connection.

edit: I entered in a conf file under /etc/X11/xorg.conf.d the following content, but this did not help:

```
Section "InputClass"
        Identifier "libinput touchpad catchall"
        MatchIsTouchpad "on"
        MatchDevicePath "/dev/input/event*"
        Driver "libinput"
EndSection
```

I have no idea how to investigate this.

Does anyone have any idea how to solve this? or how to dig deeper?

Comment: Replace the driver and then review the settings (slow down movement and gestures).

Comment: I added a file in /etc/X11/xorg.conf.d and rebooted the laptop. Lets wait if the issue is gone.

Comment: No. it did not help. I entered the content of the file in my first message